# First Order Logic - Consequence and Interpretation

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm trying to understand why this is false: $\varphi \vee \psi \models \chi \text{ iff } \varphi \models \chi \text{ or } \psi \models \chi.$

I think that the problem is that it can have two groups of interpretation and some doesn't hold for both. Any interpretation that shows why this is false will be very good accepted too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take $\varphi$ to be True, $\psi$ to be False and $\chi$ to be False.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works, but i cant understand why False |= False is something that "works". Looking at the definition of consequence i see that A |= B iff for all Interpretation that satisfies A also satisfy B, and i understand satisfies as something that leads A to become "true". So, why can i use something like that?

Comment: @David: If an interpretation satisfies $A$ then it also must satisfy $B$. But if $A$ is false then $B$ can be anything (for this interpretation).

Answer (score 1):

Do you see why this is true: $\varphi\vee\psi\models\chi$ iff $\varphi\models\chi$ and $\varphi\models\chi$?

Combined with what you thought should be true, we would have:
$\varphi\models\chi$ and $\varphi\models\chi$ iff $\varphi\models\chi$ or $\varphi\models\chi$. Do you think that should be true?

Suppose $\chi$ happens to be the same as $\varphi$. Do you think this is true:
$\varphi\vee\psi\models\varphi$ iff $\varphi\models\varphi$ or $\psi\models\varphi$?